# Xcopy with parameter running with Task Scheduler fails, but I can run it manually and works

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, xcopy

So I have a bat file that runs just fine when I double click it.  But setting it up to run with Task Scheduler and it will not run fully.

In this Bat file I use xcopy to copy two things:

Regular files.
Files modified in the last 30 days.

The "Regular files" part of this bat file runs fine with the task scheduler.  However the "Files modified in the last 30 days" does not.  (Again, running this bat file manually works.)

Contents of bat file:

```
set /p mydt=<tmpFile

set YYYY=%mydt:~6,4%
set MM=%mydt:~0,2%
set DD=%mydt:~3,2%

@echo %YYYY%
@echo %MM%
@echo %DD%

xcopy "\\TheServer\c$\TheFiles\*" C:\Dir\Files_younger_than\ /D:%MM%-%DD%-%YYYY% /Y /S
Xcopy "\\TheServer\c$\MoreFiles\*" C:\Dir\Morefiles\ /Y /S
```

Any thoughts why task scheduler is giving me issues here?

Comment: under what user does the task run? it is possible that it needs more permissions.

Comment: It runs under domain admin.  Task runs with highest privileges, set to run wheter user is logged on or not.

Comment: is the  Last Run Result different than 0 when the task is finished?

Comment: This may help you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951246

Comment: Yes - looking at the history and then Action completed in the text I get a return code of 0.

Comment: where does tmpFile get its date from? If it's not a permissions issue, it's probably a date issue. Echo out your date variables to a file and see what you get.

Comment: The tmp file is in the same directory.  I echo'd out the date and it is fine - also running the file manuarlly pulls in the date fine.  Please see answer from @The Roach that solved this issued. (It very well could be that it was not finding the tmpFile when I did not have the "Start In" set.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is on the Actions Tab.  Under Edit Action, put the bat file name in the program/script box.  Then put the directory where the Bat file was located in the "Start in (optional)" area.

This should do the trick and the file should run properly after that.

Answer (score 0):

Task scheduler runs under the `System` account by default and doesn't have access to network resources.  Change it to run under your credentials and it will have the same permissions as you.